# ImportError: cannot import name 't' from 'scipy.stats' (unknown location)

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to perform an unpaired T-test.

When I try to import the [t.test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html) function with `from scipy.stats import t`, I receive an error: `"ImportError: cannot import name 't' from 'scipy.stats' (unknown location)"`.

I am using a Jupyter notebook and have reinstalled scipy with !pip, but does not seem to help.

Comment: Is the same working in your terminal?

Comment: Just to double check - try `%pip install` from within the Jupyter notebook (it's my most trusted way of selecting the right pip env), then restart the kernel. Also, see whether you don't have any `scipy.py` etc files in your current directory. If so, move/rename those.

Comment: Tagging on Dominick's excellent suggestions, here's the background on why `%pip install` is the suggested way to go from now on and why you should no longer use an exclamation point in combination with `pip` or `conda` when working inside a Jupyter notebook since the new magic commands were added recently: [the %pip and %conda magics](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez)

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions! Will try these out